# Naming a class that represents an iCal object

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

We, as I'm sure many, have adopted the approach whereby interfaces are pre-pended with an `I`, therefore naming the class `iCal` would break the current naming convention as it isn't an interface for `Cal` (or is it?). I've had a quick Google and I'm unable to decipher what the `i` stands for, as it seems the most straight forward option to replace the `i` with it's full name, that is assuming it's short-for-something. Any advice is greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, iCal and ICal are two different things. iCal doesn't break the .net interface naming conventions, in my opinion.

Just to clarify based on Adam's comment - I wasn't saying to use it as Adam points out it breaks the convention of all types being pascal cased. My point was that iCal doesn't imply an interface.

Comment: It breaks it from the perspectives of all types being Pascal-cased. But I agree; it would not indicate (to me) that it's an interface.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the "i" stands for "internet".

You might want to call things `Rfc5545Calendar` etc, after [RFC 5545](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5545.txt) which specifies iCalendar. (RFC 2445 had some pretty nasty bits; perhaps 5545 which replaced it is better...)

Comment: +1, though I would think most people would see the lowercase first letter (i.e. `iCal` vs. `ICal`) and not immediately assume it was an interface. Whereas `Rfc5545Calendar` could be likely to make people think "Well, now I've got to go look up RCF 5545..."

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this case `iCal` doesn't break any convention because it should be called `ICal` to break the interfaces naming convention. I think that due to the problem of Interfaces namig convention the programmer that wrote this didn't want to create any problem and wanted to write an acronym where `i` is the initial letter of another word.